# LeafletJS - Clearing a map before next use

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using leafletjs to formulate a map and I am positioning markers on the map by the use of a localStorage array.

the first time that i load the map the markers come on just fine , but when i reload the map , when different markers should come on the map the same previous ones appear.

So what I'd like to know is if there is any way to clear the entire map of all its markers and popups before the next usage ?

Thanks.

Comment: please provide code sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before adding new elements to array make it empty..then add new elements to it..or add markers to layers...when you reload page just call a method removeLayer and add new layer next to it.